# simple question on torques on an ellipsoid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I have an ellipsoid, and in the reference frame where the x-, y- and z-axis are aligned with its eigenvectors I compute the torque $\vec\tau$ acting on it.

And I'm asking myself how can I quantify the speed at which the torque makes the ellipsoid rotate about its major axis.

Is the solution as simple as computing $\dot{\vec{\omega}}$ using the well know relation

$\vec\tau=I\dot{\vec{\omega}}$ ?

For instance, for an ellipsoid of constant density one has

$\vec\tau=\dfrac{M}{5}((b^2+c^2)\,\dot{\omega_x},(a^2+c^2)\,\dot{\omega_y},(a^2+b^2)\,\dot{\omega_z})$

Is there any better way to quantify how much the torque would let the ellipsoid rotate along its axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above equation won't work.  It's true that $\vec{\tau} = \dot{\vec{L}}$ in an inertial reference frame, such as the fixed "space frame".  But in the space frame, $\dot{\vec{L}} \neq \mathbf{I} \dot{\vec{\omega}}$, since $\mathbf{I}$ is changing with respect to time as well as the body is rotating.

The usual solution is to go to the "body frame" instead, which is a frame that rotates with the body.  The relationship between torque and angular momentum that holds in the body frame is now
$$
\vec{\tau} = \dot{\vec{L}} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{L}
$$
and since $\mathbf{I}$ is constant in the body frame, we have
$$
\vec{\tau} = \mathbf{I} \dot{\vec{\omega}} + \vec{\omega} \times (\mathbf{I} \vec{\omega} ).
$$
When this equation is split into its components along the principle axes of the body, the resulting three equations are often called [*Euler's equations*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics))

So if you know the torque in the body frame, you can in principle solve for $\vec{\omega}$ in the body frame as a function of time.  The resulting equations are non-linear and hard to solve in general, although various approximation methods can be used.  Alternately, if you want to find the torque required to keep the body rotating about a given axis, you can set $\vec{\omega} = $ const. and $\dot{\vec{\omega}} = 0$, and see what $\vec{\tau}$ is required (in the body frame) for this to be true.